# c# compiler doesn't resolve generic type parameters by constraints

Tags: c#, generics, generic-type-argument, nested-generics

I have the following use case:

I have created generic-endpoint strucure in my ASP.NET Core WebAPi project.

And now I want to write an extention method to `ServiceCollection` to register my `Endpoint`s to DI easily.

Now I will try to demonstrate what I want.
Let's say we have:

```
interface IEndPoint<TInput, TOutput>
{
    TOutput Execute(TInput input);
}

class StrToIntEndPoint : IEndPoint<string, int>
{
    public int Execute(string input)
    {
        return int.Parse(input);
    }
}

class ServiceCollection { }

static class ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions
{
    public static void AddScoped<TService, TImplementation>(this ServiceCollection services) where TImplementation : TService
    {

    }
}

static class MyCustomExt
{
    // Here, I have to add TInput, TOutput type parameters to AddEndpoint method too.
    public static void AddEndpoint<T, TInput, TOutput>(this ServiceCollection services) where T: IEndPoint<TInput, TOutput>
    {
        services.AddScoped<IEndPoint<TInput, TOutput>, T>();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        // Compile Error: Incorrect number of type parameters
        services.AddEndpoint<StrToIntEndPoint>();

        // fine
        services.AddEndpoint<StrToIntEndPoint, string, int>();

    }
}
```

My question is why compiler doesn't resolve `string` and `int` as type parameters for `AddEndpoint` via refering to `StrToIntEndPoint`?

Comment: This is called *partial Inference*, and *.Net* doesn't support it, its an *all-or-nothing* affair. However, depending on how far you want to go down this *rabbit-hole* and how much *type safety* you want to loose, there are *hacks* you can do, however non of them are satisfying

Comment: Arg. loose = lose

Comment: @TheGeneral thanks for the term, i didn't know, that's why I wrote code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly it’s just not the way generic constraints/arguments work. You either specify NO generic type arguments and the compiler infers all arguments, or you specify all of them.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with the following solution for my case:

```
static class MyCustomExt
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddScopedWitInterfaces<T>(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);

        Type[] interfaces = type.GetInterfaces();

        foreach (Type interfaceType in interfaces)
        {
            services.AddScoped(interfaceType, type);
        }

        return services;
    }
}
```

And register my service in `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddScopedWitInterfaces<StrToIntEndpoint>();
```